# Mysql search string in all fields slowness after version upgraded to 5.6

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, query-optimization, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5

Current mysql version is 5.5. I upgraded a copy to version to 5.6.

Below query get 15secs to execute from 5.5.
But the version 5.6 took 750+s to run same query.

Query :

```
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE *
    FROM  RECORDS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  AUTH  ON RECORDS.`id` = AUTH.`id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  STAFFCOMMENTS  ON RECORDS.`id` = STAFFCOMMENTS.`id`
    WHERE  (ODATE LIKE '%Jan%')
      AND  (ODATE LIKE '%2021%')
      AND  RECORDS.NAME <> 'CUSTOMER'
      AND  (RECORDS.NAME <> 'COURIER-ORDER')
  order BY RECORDS.ID DESC
    LIMIT  35000
```

Comment: always add create table for all tables invilved and a EXPLAIN SELECT * to see which indexes are used

Comment: What does the syntax "RECORDS BY" mean?

Comment: How much RAM?  Are the my.cnf files identical?  How many rows in `RECORDS`?  Which table is `ODATE` in?  What is the datatype of `ODATE`?

Comment: Serious question: Why bother to upgrade a server to a software version that's no longer supported? 5.6 reached end-of-support in Feb 2021.  Why not go for the latest stable software version? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Release_history

Comment: Thanks all. My DB engine was MYISAM in mysql 5.5 version. I changed engine to InnoDB in mysql 5.6 version. It fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ODATE` is of datatype `DATE` or `DATETIME` (which it should be!), change

```
       (ODATE LIKE '%Jan%')
  AND  (ODATE LIKE '%2021%')
```

to

```
       ODATE >= '2021-01-01'
  AND  ODATE  < '2021-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Then show us the indexes so we can judge whether they can be improved.